# How to write Laravel eloquent where clause as normal mysql query?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to use a string as it is such as:

```php
$x = "field1 > 1 && field 2 LIKE '%z%'...";
```

Instead of breaking the above string into chunks like:

```php
->where('field1', '>', 1)
->where('field2', 'LIKE', '%z%')
```

The reason is that I have many `where` statements written like above in an old project and I would like to use them as they are in a new project with eloquent queries.

Comment: As a user already answered your question, you can. But I personally do not recommend using `raw SQL queries` as Eloquent is very well understood and raw queries can introduce all sort of issues from security to a typo in any keyword, also not to mention that it is not "customizable" as Eloquent. I did not understand what you meant with "like above in an old project". Eloquent queries are mostly written like your second code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use eloquent with raw query like this :-

```
User::whereRaw('id = 1')->get()
```

or you can use DB raw query to do that like this :-

```
DB::select('select * from user where field > :field', ['field' => 1]);
```

you should avoid to concatenate vars come from request to your query so use bind to secure your query.

Comment: Perfect!  Thgank you @MohamedAhmed.  Security is not an issue as this is only for a few trusted registered users on the back end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereRaw()`

```
->where('field1 > 1 AND field2 LIKE "%z%"')
```

With variables

```
$str = 'z';
$field1 =1;
->where("field1 > $field1 AND field2 LIKE '%$str%' ")
```